# How to add the count from one query into another query

Tags: sql, oracle

My first query looks like this:

```
SELECT location, COUNT(*) as sections
FROM section
GROUP BY location
```

which gives me:

Answer (score 1):

Simply join the queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT location, COUNT(*) as sections
  FROM section
  GROUP BY location
)
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT s.location, COUNT(*) as students
  FROM enrollment e 
  INNER JOIN section s ON s.section_id = e.section_id
  GROUP BY s.location
) USING (location)
ORDER BY location;
```

Another option is to group the enrollments by section, join and group by location then.

```
SELECT
  location,
  COUNT(*) as sections,
  SUM(students_in_section) AS students
FROM section s
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT section_id, COUNT(*) as students_in_section
  FROM enrollment
  GROUP BY section_id
) e ON e.section_id = s.section_id
GROUP BY s.location
ORDER BY s.location;
```

Another option is to join the tables and count distinct sections and distinct enrollments.

```
SELECT
  location,
  COUNT(DISTINCT s.section_id) as sections,
  COUNT(DISTINCT e.enrollment_id) AS students
FROM section s
LEFT JOIN enrollment e ON e.section_id = s.section_id
GROUP BY s.location
ORDER BY s.location;
```

Comment: Count distinct rowids of each table will provide more accurate result independently of the data model and identification of the primary key for each table

Comment: @astentx: This is a good advice.

Comment: ... but should be noted that it is valid only for plain tables

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` to count the unique sections for each location

```sql
  SELECT location, COUNT (DISTINCT s.section_id) AS sections, COUNT (*) AS students
    FROM enrollment e INNER JOIN section s ON s.section_id = e.section_id
GROUP BY location
```

Comment: this isn't the same results. it will only count the sections that exist in enrollment. Combining the two queries will give the count of all sections in a location regardless of their representation in enrollment